# Ajax form submit by clicking a checkbox with cakephp 2.0

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

The aim : a table, with a person on each line, and checkboxes, clicking a checkbox
submit a form, for now one form for each checkbox.

(http://iufm-web.ujf-grenoble.fr/crip/images/extrait_tableau_dossiers.png)

I've managed that with cakephp 2.0, but each submit reload the entire page (how many lines ? perhaps several hundred, the maximum is another question)

I want it to be very reactive, so I thought to use ajax to reload only the line clicked.

I've tried to use Js->submit, but it's not compatible with checkboxes.

I wonder what I should use for the action of each form, as a controller action causes the page to be reloaded or redirected.

Edit : I've followed Dave's suggestion and in the fragment view (that fill the table row) :

```
echo $this->Form->input('recu',array('type'=>'checkbox', 
                     'value'=>true, 
                     'id'=>'recu'.$ilignetot, 
                     'hiddenField'=>true, 
                     'div' =>false, 
                     'label' =>false, 
                      'checked'=>$user['User'['recu'], 
                 ))."\n";   

$this->Js->get('#recu'.$ilignetot)->event('change', 
    $this->Js->request(array(
        'controller'=>'users',
        'action'=>'admin_dossier_recu2'
        ), array(
        'update'=>'#'.$lineid,
        'async' => true,
        'method' => 'post',
        'dataExpression'=>true,
        'data'=> $this->Js->serializeForm(array(
            'isForm' => false,
            'inline' => true
            ))
        ))
    );
```

In the controller action admin_dossier_recu2, I save the form, and return the fragment, specifying :

```
      $this->layout = 'ajax';
```

Thanks for the hint, my previous attempts were wrong. Unfortunately, my solution does'nt work with IE8 but it works well with firefox and chrome. Now, I would have a visual effect, for the user to know the data is actually saved, but perhaps should I ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

Use [javascripts `onchange()` event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) and have it call a function that does all your ajax.

You can also do some logic to determine if said changed checkbox is checked or not before you do your ajax...etc etc.